# Stop the dragable event when this related div tag reached 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was tried to drag the `div (class = scale_roll)` tag by dragging the  another `div (class =scale_cap)`.

When the div `scale_cap` is dragging it's related `scale_roll` div tag also move.

But my problem is `scale_cap` dragging cann't stop  when the `scale_roll` div tag was reached 100%.

I want to don't drag the div tag after the visible area. or i want to drag only the 100%.

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uj6T6/47/)

Comment: Please post relevant code here as well, and not only on external sites. They might not be around forever, and all might not have access to them.

Comment: @Khaja What you actually want? You want to add the handler to the div tag.?

Comment: @mkHun Yes exactly i want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you fully read the [Draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handl:). jQuery have the option for add the handle to the div. 
So you don't work hard for add the handle to the drggable element.

create the `handle <div>` inside the draggable div. Then add and use this

```
 $( ".scale_roll" ).draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: 'parent',
    handle:'.scale_cap',
 });
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YvJhE/631/)